# What's the complexity of this estate-division game?

Tags: gt.game-theory

Alice and Bob are splitting their deceased uncle Charlie's estate (a finite collection $X$ of discrete items) according to his wishes.  First A picks an item, then B, then A, and so on.

Alice and Bob each have additive utility functions $u_A, u_B$, so that if Alice ends up with the set $Y \subseteq X$, her utility is $\sum_{y \in Y}u_A(y)$.

These utility functions are common knowledge, as is the fact that Alice and Bob are perfectly rational utility-maximizers.  This implies that the players will *not* always follow a greedy approach, grabbing the item of greatest worth to them; they will be more strategic.

So, what is the computational complexity of implementing the players' strategies?  It's doable in polynomial space, and that's all I know.

Comment: There is a bit of a modeling uncertainty in this problem: how does Alice (or Bob) choose between two outcomes in which her utility is the same?  One way to avoid this is to assume that no two subsets of X are assigned equal utility.  Then I claim that the outcome under rational play is uniquely determined, even if the order of item choice is not.  (Simple proof by induction.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this paper will be of interest though I don't know if it addresses complexity issues:

http://or.journal.informs.org/cgi/content/abstract/19/2/270

or

http://www.jstor.org/pss/169267

Comment: Wow--you nailed it!  This paper gives a very simple, efficient algorithm for exactly the problem above, with a slick proof of correctness.  Thanks!